# Unable to remove sql server 2014 files

Tags: sql-server, uninstallation

I am trying to remove /unistall all SQL server 2014 related files .. I follow this setup

https://www.daktronics.com/support/kb/Pages/DD3522855.aspx

but still these files are not removed .. what should I do

[image sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1czLU.png)

Comment: Did you reboot after uninstalling SQL Server?